# How to put space in tab title in dojo?

Tags: codeigniter

i am using dojo toolkit with php codeigniter 2.1.0 and i want to put space in tab name wherever necessary.

Anyone has any solution??

My code is :

```
<div id="setupParty" data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem"
            onclick="addPartyTab('AddParty');">Manage <u>P</u>arty</div
```

If i will directly write as :

```
 <div id="setupParty" data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem"
            onclick="addPartyTab('Add Party');">Manage <u>P</u>arty</div
```

then it throws error

I want my tab to be displayed with name as "Add Party"

can anyone suggest me solution for this???

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error does it throw?
how does the code in addPartyTab look like?

The following should work in any case:

```
onclick="addPartyTab('Add&nbsp;Party');">
```

However, this may not be an ideal solution. You need to look into your addPartyTab function to first, ensure the text with embedded space is coming through fine (and i dont see any reason why it shouldnt) and then examine the code in that function to ensure it is being processed correctly - i suspect somewhere in there you will find why it is breaking.

In general, you can set title on a dijit tab (which is typically a contentpane) directly even if the title contains spaces without any issue. Following is a typical way of doing it:

```
dijit.byId("myTabContentPane").set("title", "Add Party - Hurray!");
```

where myTabContentPane is the id of the contentpane that makes up that tab

Comment: thnx for your reply, but it is not working and it shows this error "String contains an invalid character" which is same error which is displayed if i directly put space in tab name e.g Add Party then it will show the same above error......if possible please send another solution and thnx again for your instance